# Considering what beats what in limits

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

When we consider limits we often consider what a function tends towards. So we consider what 'beats' what within the function.

For example in my lecture notes it states

> Polynomials are beaten by exponentials

But how do we know this? Is there a test or a measure of what 'beats' what?

Comment: It is all based on the rate of growth of the function that the limit is being taken of. Exponentials 'grow' in value faster than polynomials, polynomials of a higher degree faster than those of a lower degree, etc. In other words, intuitively, the higher the rate of growth of a certain 'component' of the function, the more it will take to overtake that 'component', resulting in it beating out others with a lesser rate of growth. I hope this helps.

Comment: @R.Kap Is there a more concrete way of looking at it, instead of just intuition? Often intuition can be misleading.

Comment: Okay. Consider the following limit:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\inf}\frac{2^x}{x^2}$$
We can see that, as x grows unbounded towards infinity, `2^x` will eventually always results in a higher value than the polynomial (I won't include a formal proof of it here) which we can see when when `x=1` and then `2^x=2` while `x^2=1`, when `x=10` during which `2^x=1024` and `x^2=100`, etc. We can see that when we estimate the rate of growth of both functions for the interval $[2,10]$, we get $2^{x}=\frac{1024-2}{10-1}\approx{114}$ whereas $x^2=\frac{100-1}{10-1}=11$ and can thus now see that the growth of...

Comment: ...$2^x$ is much bigger than that of $x^2$, resulting in the fact that as $x$ grows unbounded, so does $2^x$, more so than $x^2$.

Comment: Another (as useful) rule of thumb : "logarithms are beaten by polynomials"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A commonly used way of comparing the growth rates of functions over the reals is *asymptotic notation*, first introduced in number theory by Landau and later used extensively in the analysis of algorithms. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LandauSymbols.html for more.

The most commonly encountered asymptotic notation is "big-O" notation.

Let $f,g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We say that $f = O(g)$ if there exists a $c \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ and a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x) \leq c \cdot g(x)$ whenever $x \geq n_0$.

Informally, $f = O(g)$ should be read as stating that $g$ will eventually outgrow $f$ "up to a constant factor".

It is now easy to see that for every $n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $x^{n_1} = O(x^{n_1})$ whenever $n_1 \geq n_2$.

Moreover, we have that $x^n = O(2^x)$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$. It is this fact that lets us say exponential functions "beat" polynomials.